# how to direct users to different home pages depending on a property they possess, stored in firebase database?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication

Okay, so I'm writing a login page that should ideally direct users to one of the two different home pages(home-staff and home-manager) depending on the value of their property 'tag'('tag' can either be 'staff' or 'admin') which is stored in the realtime database in firebase. Hence, I need to retrieve that data and check for the value of that property and decide where to direct them.

One more thing that it should simultaneously do, is giving an alert message if the entered email or password is incorrect or if the user doesn't have an account.

I've tried to incorporate all of this in my 'login.ts' page and I'm getting a run-time error saying 'Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: ' (my first argument is user.email)
Here is my code. Please Help

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
import { AngularFireDatabase,FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { HomeManagerPage } from '../home-manager/home-manager';
import { HomeStaffPage } from '../home-staff/home-staff';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  user= {} as User;
  public fireAuth: any;
  public userProfile: any;
  public userTag: any;
  public t: any;
    
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public angfire:AngularFireAuth) 
  {
      this.fireAuth=firebase.auth();
      this.userProfile=firebase.database().ref('users');
  }



  viewUser(userEmail: any)
  {
     var userRef= this.userProfile.child(userEmail);
       
       return userRef.once('value');
  
  }


  goToSignup(params)
  {
      if (!params) params = {};
      this.navCtrl.push(SignupPage);
  }


  goToLogin(params)
  {
      if (!params) params = {};
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
  }


  displayUser(theUserEmail)
  {
    var that=this;
    
    this.viewUser(theUserEmail).then(snapshot=>
     {
       that.userTag=snapshot.val().tag;

     })
     return this.userTag;
  }


  async login(user:User)
  { 
    
    this.angfire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
    .then(user => {
      this.t=this.displayUser(user.email);

      if(this.t=='staff'){this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomeStaffPage);}
      else{this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomeManagerPage);}
      
      
      }, err => {
     let msg;
     switch (err['code'])
     { 
       // SWITCH THE CODE RETURNED TO SEE WHAT MESSAGE YOU'LL DISPLAY
       case "auth/wrong-password":
          msg= "Email or Password is wrong.";
          break;
           
       case "auth/user-not-found":
          msg= 'User not found.'; 
          break;

       case "auth/invalid-email":
          msg= 'Email or Password is wrong.';
          break;
     }

       alert(msg);
    });//.then ends here
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Does that snippet belongs to a service? a component?

Comment: This belongs to a component. All of this is written inside a class .

Comment: could you add that?

Comment: Yes i do store information in my database. It is the default structure of the firebase realtime database. This is because the differentiating factor 'tag' is not a part of the default 'user properties' in firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two things:

1 - I think you have to much code for a simple thing like this, we can reduce it.

2 - I highly adivise you saving your user in it's uuid created when the user creates an account, it's safier. So you'll have and structure like

```
Your_BD
|_ users
   |_ user_uuid
      |_ email: email
      |_ tag: tag
```

So what you need to do is: `Login > get user email > get the user node > get tag`, the problem is that Angular (or TS, i forgot who, sorry) is non-blocking, so it'll not wait for the return of your functions to check the tag and send the user to a page, so use the promise returned by firebase methods to manipulate what to execute and to execute your code right.

In your login function you can do this (i'll not use the error part):

```
async login(user:User)
{ 
  this.angfire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
  .then(user => {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.email).once('value', snapshot =>{
      if(snapshot.val().tag == 'staff'){
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomeStaffPage);
      } else {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomeManagerPage);
      }
    })
  }, err =>{...})
}
```

Hope this helps :D